# Matlab - Parallel filesearch with afterEach

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing

Im trying to implement a function in Matlab, that searches for files and does that in parallel to speed up the process. Ive successfully implemented that in the following function:

```
function matches = searchfordata(starting_path, search_depth, checkFunction)

arguments
    
    starting_path {isfolder}
    search_depth int64
    checkFunction function_handle
    
end
tic;

folders = struct('name', '' , 'folder', starting_path);

dataMap = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'any');


next_folders = [];
matches = [];
no_folders = height(folders);
current_depth = 0;
total_folders = 0;

if search_depth < 0
    search_depth = 9001;
end

while current_depth <= search_depth && no_folders > 0
    
    
    total_folders = total_folders + no_folders;
    
    
    
    
    parfor n = 1:no_folders
        
        
        path = strcat(folders(n).folder, filesep, folders(n).name);
        [files, cfolders] = filesandfolders(path);
        
        if height(files) > 0
            check = checkFunction(files);
        else
            check = [];
        end
        
        matches = [matches;check];
        next_folders = [next_folders; cfolders];
        
        
    end
    
    
    if height(matches) > 0
        dataMap(current_depth) = matches;
        matches = [];
    end
    
    folders = next_folders;
    no_folders = height(folders);
    next_folders = [];
    
    current_depth = current_depth + 1;
    
end

matches = dataMap;
toc;
end
```

Relevant other functions/classes for this:

```
function [files, folders] = filesandfolders(path)
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
directory_contents = dir(path);
files = directory_contents(~[directory_contents.isdir]);
folders = directory_contents([directory_contents.isdir]);
folders = folders(~ismember({folders.name}, {'.', '..'}));
end
```

Basically a dir, which splits the result into the files and folders and removes the "." and ".." from the folder results.

```
function boolobject = checkFiles(files)
%CHECKFILES Checks given files for powercycler files
%   Detailed explanation goes here
%cyclingregex = 'cycling_parameters\.xml';
%transientregex = '\.(pol|par|raw)$';
cyclingregex = '\.txt$';
transientregex = '\.txt$';
matching_cycling = regexpi({files.name}, cyclingregex, 'Match');
matching_transient = regexpi({files.name}, transientregex, 'Match');
cycling_indices = ~cellfun(@isempty, matching_cycling);
transient_indices = ~cellfun(@isempty, matching_transient);


boolobject = FolderData(files(1).folder);
boolobject.cyclingData = any(cycling_indices);
boolobject.rthData = any(transient_indices);


if boolobject.cyclingData || boolobject.rthData
    
    return
else
    boolobject = [];
end


end
```

This gets the list of files from filesandfolders as input and filters for the files I am searching for. I changed this to txt for better reproduceability. The output of this function is this class:

```
classdef FolderData < handle
    %FOLDERDATA Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here
    
    properties
        folder %folderpath
        rthData %bool, true if this folder contains rth-data files
        cyclingData %bool, true if this folder contains cycling-data files
    end
    
    methods
        function this = FolderData(path)
            this.rthData = false;
            this.cyclingData = false;
            this.folder = path;
        end
                
    end
end
```

Which just says what files were found and in which folder.

The actual search function at the top takes 8-30 seconds on my drives and is working. Now I thought I could maybe speed this up a little more with afterEach. The basic idea being, that the if the contents of the folders that are being processed in the parfor loop are very different in quantity, theres a single folder holding back the process, because it needs to finish before the function can resume its work after the parfor loop.

For that I have created the following script:

```
clc;
clear all;

path = 'D:\';
if isempty(gcp('nocreate'))
    parpool(4);
end
fun = @checkFiles;

output = searchparforae(path, fun);
%output = searchforae(path, fun);
%output = searchfordata(path, 100, fun);



function matches = searchparforae(starting_path, checkFunction)

tic;


folder_que = parallel.pool.DataQueue;
matches = [];

listener = afterEach(folder_que, @search_folder);
starting_path = struct('folder', starting_path, 'name', '');
search_folder(starting_path);


    function search_folder(input)
        
        parfor n = 1:height(input)
            folder_path = strcat(input(n).folder, filesep, input(n).name);
            fprintf(1, folder_path);
            fprintf(1, '\n');
            [files, folders] = filesandfolders(folder_path);
            if height(files) > 0
                check = checkFunction(files);
            else
                check = [];
            end
            
            matches = [matches;check];
            send(folder_que, folders);
        end
    end
toc;
end

function matches = searchforae(starting_path, checkFunction)

tic;


folder_que = parallel.pool.DataQueue;
matches = [];

listener = afterEach(folder_que, @search_folder);
starting_path = struct('folder', starting_path, 'name', '');
search_folder(starting_path);


    function search_folder(input)
        
        for n = 1:height(input)
            folder_path = strcat(input(n).folder, filesep, input(n).name);
            fprintf(1, folder_path);
            fprintf(1, '\n');
            [files, folders] = filesandfolders(folder_path);
            if height(files) > 0
                check = checkFunction(files);
            else
                check = [];
            end
            
            matches = [matches;check];
            send(folder_que, folders);
        end
    end
toc;
end
```

The two functions "searchforae" and "searchparforae" are exactly the same, except for the loop. As it might be obvious from the names "searchforae" has a for loop, while "searchparforae" has a parfor loop.

Now searchforae is not working at all. The print outputs show, that searchforae is only processing files in the initially given directory and the directories directly below that. Print outputs:

```
D:\
D:\$RECYCLE.BIN
D:\Downloads
D:\OneDriveTemp
D:\Programme
D:\Repositories
D:\Sonstiges
D:\Spiele
D:\System Volume Information
D:\Uni
D:\Uni2
D:\Users
D:\Zwischenablage
```

The searchparforae function in contrast is working just as well as the searchfordata function at the top. But instead of 8-30 seconds its taking 5-10 minutes. Am I using afterEach wrong? Why is it taking that long? Also why isnt the searchforae function working correctly even tho the only difference is a for loop instead of a parfor compared to searchparforae?

Comment: Is your parfor loop at the top actually run in parallel? I’d be very surprised, since your output arrays grow every iteration. By the way, `matches = [matches;check]` is a very inefficient way to grow the array, it is better to do `matches(end+1) = check`

Comment: Im pretty sure I actually tested that and when I replaced the parfor with a for it was slower (although not by that much). I didnt know about array(end+1) = newElement, thats not giving an out of bounds? Also the array doesnt actually grow each iteration since check is [] if there were none of the files I want found, which is most of the time.

Comment: @CrisLuengo So I tested again. My function ath the top searchfordata, takes around 8 seconds to complete with a parfor loop and around 17 with a for loop, so it should actually be running in parallel. I tried your concatenating suggestion ```matches(end+1) = check```, but this got me an error while trying it in the for loop and in the parfor loop its not even allowed in the first place.